# Restore a deleted workflow in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, restore

A colleague of mine just did something rather stupid and deleted a vital workflow on a production machine running Sharepoint 2010.

Since we're not hosting the machine, there's no backup (yes yes, I know... I KNOW... it's not my fault and the person responsible for this lack of foresight needs to have some very bad things done to him) but there's a complete transaction log weighting over 50GBs.

Is there any way to get that workflow back?

EDIT: Actually, there ARE backups, but they're currently inaccessible (don't ask me why - I don't know). Supposedly after the weekend these should be available, but it would be nice to restore the system to a working condition sooner.

Comment: I'd say the stupid thing was not having a backup and giving the colleague the ability to delete the workflow in the first place, and the person who allowed such a condition to exist is the one who should have very bad things done to them.

Comment: Hey... I'm a developer, not a sys-admin. But now it's "all hands on deck" to try and solve  this issue, if you're hinting at "bad things done" being done to me. >.<

Comment: Not at all, but after you recover from this I'd definitely re-evaluate the access permissions in Sharepoint.

Comment: ...or backup availability. Stupid things can happen. Backups are a fallback. Sounds like multiple levels of fail here.

Comment: I understand that Sharepoint backups and restores are somewhat of a PITA. Workflows for example may or may not be backed up by backing up the content database. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261687.aspx#ChooseWhatProtect

Comment: It IS multiple levels of fail. The backup system on the hosting machine was busted for some reason (I only know this much), and AFAIK we only have a 1,5 week-old snapshot... :( In our defence, we're not administering the hosting machine and don't have direct control over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted workflows will appear in the SharePoint recycle bin. You can restore them out of here. Do that and the workflow will show up in SharePoint Designer again. Unfortunately restoring will not re-associate the workflow with the list again so it won't actually do anything useful. It will however let you view it in SharePoint Designer and create a new workflow with the same settings.

Comment: After restoring I published the WF and it works.